# Find inequality for gaussian density

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, inequality

Let $C>0$ be a fixed constant. Is it true that
$$Cx^2 e^{-x^2}\leq e^{-\frac{x^2}{C}}?$$

More generally, if we have a power $x^p$ in front of the exponential, do we have that
$$(C^{1/2}x)^p\leq e^{-\frac{x^2}{C^{p/2}}}?$$
or at least, something similar? I want to upperbound a polynomial times a Gaussian kernel by just a Gaussian kernel adjusting the variance: that is
$$Cp(x)e^{-x^2} \leq \exp \left\{-\frac{x^2}{C?}\right\}.$$

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In this generality, no: take $C=1000$, $x=1$, so you would get $1000 /e\leq e^{-1/1000}$.

Comment: If you multiply both sides of your first inequality by $e^{x^2}$, you get $Cx^2\le e^{(1-C^{-1})x^2}$. You would at least need $C>1$ for the exponent on the right to be positive, but then it looks hopeful, does it not? You might want to investigate the inequality $Cx^2\le e^{Ax^2}$ more generally. Or with $u=x^2$, $Cu\le e^{Au}$, for $u\ge 0$. For any $A$ there should be a largest $C$ so this holds – for that $C$, the line $y=Cu$ is tangent to $y=e^{Au}$, so there is a relation between $A$ and $C$ that you can look at.

Comment: Aha. The thing is I have $\frac{x^2}{t^3}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}$ and $x\geq 1$ so I am pretty sure that $\frac{x^2}{t^3}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} \leq e^{-C x^2} \leq e^{-2C}$ since $x\geq 1$ where $C$ depends on $t$ but I don't know how to justify or which inequality to use. I have to be careful here because $t$ can be as small as we want.